How can I detect what object player touched on screen in Godot 4.2 3D scene
I am making a mobile 3D game using Godot 4.2. My issue is, I want to move my character only if I touch and drag it, if I touch other places on screen nothing should happen. Should I use Area3D or there is other solution?
What I have now is that wherever I touch and drag my player will follow. I also have the virtual joystick asset, but I don't want to use it rather. The movement I need is much similar to mechanics in Spider Nest game.

Perhaps this covers your question: How to raycast down to the floor plane to determine world space coordinates in Godot

Not actually but I figured out. In case anyone needs. I added an area3D with collision shape. Added signal on input event to turn dragging variable to true, then my control ov character is in unhandled input event and there as soon as event is not pressed, dragging turns false so characyer stops moving and plays idle animation. I'll pazte here the code if it will be needed to others.
